# Continually getting file-not-found error from csv reader in python

Tags: python, csv, file-not-found

I'm very new to coding, so hopefully, this problem is easier to solve then I think. I'm trying read and interact with a CSV file in python but every time I try the code returns a file/directory not found error. I've simply printed the code and know that the file can, in fact, be found and used, and I know that the file can only be called upon when printed as .csv.csv. Why is this file/directory not found error occuring when I try to call upon the csv file for this specific block of code?? Please help.

The error I get is:

> ```
> $ python second_lesson.py
> What show or movie are you looking for? Friends
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "second_lesson.py", line 17, in <module>
>     with open(csvpath, newline="") as csvfile:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\Downloads\\netflix_ratings.csv.csv'
> ```

```
import os
import csv

video = input("What show or movie are you looking for? ")

csvpath = os.path.join("C:", "Desktop", "Python2", "netflix_ratings.csv.csv")

found = False

with open(csvpath, newline="") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] == video:
            print(row[0] + " is rated " + row[1] + " with a rating of " + row[5])


            found = True

    if found is False:
        print("Sorry about this, we don't seem to have what you are looking for!")
```

Comment: Please post the exact error traceback as well.

Comment: why are there two .csv's in the path

Comment: Also, is `netflix_ratings.csv.csv` a typo or is that the actual name? The extension is there twice.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison I didn't realize my file extensions were hidden at first

Comment: There is a way of showing all extension on a Windows device ... I recommend doing that.

Comment: Try dropping one of the .csv's

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison I've tried and that does not work.

Comment: Then it's probable that the file does not exist at that path. I recommend checking from a dos shell that the file exists with that path.

Comment: I guess the path is not correct it should be users like that, please copy the path from properties, and personally I recommend not to save any file on Desktop

Comment: @raunakrathi the path is definitely correct. I've tried moving the file from desktop and changing the path but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @Dessamol please try path like D:/any folder...such path would work for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\Downloads\\netflix_ratings.csv.csv'
```

is way different from

```
    csvpath = os.path.join("C:", "Desktop", "Python2", "netflix_ratings.csv.csv")
```

=> C:\Desktop\Python2\netflix_ratings.csv.csv

I suggest fixing the path or putting a file in the path specified in the error.

Comment: Okay, i've fixed the path. I moved the file to my downloads folder and changed the path to csvpath = os.path.join("C:", "Users", "mas34", "Downloads", "netflix_ratings.csv"). It still isn't working though. I'm certain that the file is in the correct path.

Comment: I suggest researching your paths with a directory walker which output a listing of all the files in each directory. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+directory+walker&atb=v110-1&ia=qa

Comment: You could also try running the script from the same directory as your input file - then from the parent directory - then the next parent.

Comment: The path itself is wrong for some reason ... the invalid assumption(s) you have about the path is the next thing for you to investigate.